# Iptables rule for server accessed remotely via DHCP

Tags: server, iptables, syntax

Sorry to ask this question - but I have been browsing forums and threads on this subject and seem to confuse myself more than actually getting any clarity. All I need is a short and concise answer for this problem:

How do a setup a (chain) rule in iptables which rejects any source which fails to gain access to the server after XX attempts within YY minutes, so that any further attempt to contact the server is rejected before password is being matched for ZZ minutes. After ZZ minutes after the last attempt to connect, the rule must allow the same source to retry its attempt as if it had never attempted to reconnect before.

- I assume this has to be written as a new chain rule.
- I assume the chain rule has to be saved to iptables, so that the rule is resumed
  at reboot.
- I assume the chain rule needs some kind of logging.

My problem is that *I don't understand the* iptables *syntax* disregarding how much I study it, and hence I'm grateful for the shortest "script type" answer on this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to be honest, there is a bit of a learning curve to iptables.

First, you can use ufw to start. ubw is a powerful command line tool and the advantage is the syntax is similar to iptables.

```
sudo ufw enable
sudo ufw limit 22
```

Here I am limiting port 22, you can use any port you wish.

https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/firewall.html

Again the advantage is ufw will automate much of this and ease your learning process.

If you want to use iptables, you at a minimum need to learn to save and restore your rules.

```
sudo iptables-save > /etc/iptables.save
sudo iptables-restore /etc/iptables.save
```

You can edit `/etc/iptables.save`, the syntax is straight forward enough.

When trying rules from remote, use `iptables-apply` to prevent a lockout

```
sudo iptables-apply /etc/iptables.save
```

To restore your rules on boot, one of several methods is to add this to /etc/rc.local

```
iptables-restore /etc/iptables.save
```

Other options listed in the Ubuntu iptables wiki page (see below).

The iptables syntax is

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 30/minute --limit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT
```

To LOG, add a LOG, but unless you are going to monitor your logs, use snort. logging iptables, IMO, is more helpful for debugging.

See man iptables, [Ubuntu wiki iptables](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

Some people find [my iptables web page](http://bodhizazen.com/Tutorials/iptables) helpful to start.

To answer your comment, see these rules

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m tcp -m state --state NEW -m recent --set --name SSH --rsource

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m recent --update --seconds 600 --hitcount 8 --rttl --name SSH --rsource -j DROP

iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/techblog/article/block_brute_force_attacks_with_iptables/

The caveat is , it depends on the service. ssh is configured to allow so many attempts at password authentication 9see `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` ), so each connection gives 6 password attempts.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs - especially the link to your blog - I am not fully confident yet :-)

When I translate my own question ("How to setup a chain rule in iptables...") I stil miss the following:

:-$ iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 30/minute --limit -burst 5 -j ACCEPT

Here I assume that XX attempts = "-burst 5". 
But is "--limit 30/minute" the same as "YY minutes" i.e. the monitored time window?
And I cannot figure out how "ZZ minutes" i.e. the penalty time for failure to validly connect, is present?

Comment: There is an error in the answer, `--limit -burst` should be `--limit-burst`. I found the drawing in the [Packet Filtering HOWTO](http://www.iptables.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.3) the clearest visualization of how the limit module works.

Comment: Have done a bit more homework and the solution doesn't do the job.
I've added my problem child here http://paste.ubuntu.com/785667/
in hope for a better idea.